# I have a Blogs/News project and confused about the use of getStaticProps and getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have search a lot and watched YouTube videos but my confusion remain the same.

I know the meaning and purpose getStaticProps and getServerSideProps in Next.js:

- getStaticProps pre-renders the page at build time and it is good for
  SEO as per Next.js documentation
- getServerSideProps pre-renders the page on each request

My scenario: I am working on Blog/News Project where there will be different categories such as Technology, Entertainment, Sports, Education, etc.

### getStaticProps()

So I am using the getStaticProps() for rendering the news cards at frontend, and when the user click on it the single news page opens
at single news page I again fetching the single post data by requesting server in getStaticProps() and also here at the same page I am using getStaticPath() to populate all possible posts.

### getServerSideProps()

And I am using this function for the CMS/Dashboard where admin can post and get statistics of all categories, all post, all comments, and so on.

So my question is that is this approach is good and also where these two methods fit well in this scenario.